# Selecting columns that are at most two days old from the current date [SQLite3]

Tags: sql, sqlite

My goal is to select all entries that are no more than 2 days old from the current date. I have this table. (Also assume that the current is 20-1-2021 for convenience):
[image]

And this is the sql statement I am currently using: `SELECT * FROM "transaction" WHERE fbydate >= date('now', '-1 day')`. Which results in the following output:
[image]

I don't want to get a date that's 3 days old from now. So what can be done here?

Comment: What is the data type of the column `fbydate`?

Comment: The column data type of `fbydate` is `DATE`

Comment: Change the format of your dates to YYYY-MM-DD. SQLite's date function does not work with any other format.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. I missed out a 0 when stating that it's january. It's supposed to be 01 not 1